# Transform animation can't be reused

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cgaffinetransform

I have a circle view `buttonView` where I apply a `CGAffineTransform` in a UIView animation like this:

```
func animateButton() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
                        self.buttonView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                    }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 3.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
                        self.buttonView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
                }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
                        if canAnimateButton {
                               animateButton()
                        }
                })
}
```

This animation is in a function which is called itself (recursive) to crate a infinite cycle.

Then I stop the animation where the view is touched with:

```
    buttonView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

When the button action is ended, I wanna relaunch the animation by calling the same function `animateButton()`.

My issue: The animation doesn't work and the transforms is applied instantly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By calling buttonView.layer.removeAllAnimations() that doesn't stop the recursive loop as the completion handler will still be called.

Instead of creating this recursive loop you should look into using CATransition instead as it gives you more finite control over UI animations.

Comment: No because I have a condition which check if a bool is true before calling back the function (see update).

Comment: I think CATransition isn't the best library to do what I want.

Comment: For doing recursive animations that are required to be stopped and started randomly on user input then I strongly recommend you don't use UIView animations as it would be a hacky solution and would just end up being buggy. Although CATransition is more advanced it is definitely the best solution in my opinion.

Comment: I don't find any method on Google to use CATransition for the result I want.